# Apps that read or write data outside its designated container area will be rejected

Tags: ipad, ios6

I am developing an app that sends data from the app to an sql server. I have read in the App Store guidelines (point 2.6) that "Apps that read or write data outside its designated container area will be rejected". Does that mean I will not be able to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm pretty sure they're just referring to the designated "sandbox" each app is assigned to. Each app has their own documents directory to save local files, and I believe they're just warning you not to attempt to write outside of this (if you were even able to on non-jailbroken devs). They also don't want you attempting to access other apps that you don't have permission to access.

I've had several apps go to the store that write to and read from Google App Engine servers and they've been accepted with no problem. So I think you'll be good to go saving data to your own server.